# Group By clause in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

## Aim:

I would like to query the table to pick only the latest version of each item.

## Question:

1. Why does **Query1** work in `SQLite` (I was thinking the `group by` clause would throw an error, because `select` statement contains the column `content` and it not part of the `group by` clause) ?
2. Would **Query1** throw an error in `Oracle` ?
3. Is **Query1** better than **Query2** ?
4. Is there a better way to write the query ?

## Query1:

```
select item_id, 
       max(version_number), 
       content
from item_version
group by item_id;
```

## Query2:

```
select iv.*
from item_version iv, 
     (select item_id, 
             max(version_number) latest_version_number
      from item_version
      group by item_id) liv
where iv.item_id = liv.item_id
  and iv.version_number = liv.latest_version_number;
```

## Setting up the table:

```
create table item_version(
    item_id              varchar,
    version_number       integer,
    content              varchar,
    primary key (item_id, version_number)
);


insert into item_version values (1, 1, null);
insert into item_version values (2, 1, "Content A");
insert into item_version values (2, 2, "Content B");
insert into item_version values (3, 1, "Content C");
insert into item_version values (3, 2, null);
insert into item_version values (4, 1, "Content D");
insert into item_version values (4, 2, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause):

> In most SQL implementations, output columns of an aggregate query may only reference aggregate functions or columns named in the GROUP BY clause. It does not make good sense to reference an ordinary column in an aggregate query because each output row might be composed from two or more rows in the input table(s).
>
> SQLite does not impose this restriction. The output columns from an aggregate query can be arbitrary expressions that include columns not found in GROUP BY clause.
>
> With SQLite (but not any other SQL implementation that we know of) if an aggregate query contains a single min() or max() function, then the values of columns used in the output are taken from the row where the min() or max() value was achieved. If two or more rows have the same min() or max() value, then the columns values will be chosen arbitrarily from one of those rows.
>
> For example to find the highest paid employee:
>
> `SELECT max(salary), first_name, last_name FROM employee;`
>
> In the query above, the values for the first_name and last_name columns will correspond to the row that satisfied the max(salary) condition.
>
> If a query contains no aggregate functions at all, then a GROUP BY clause can be added as a substitute of DISTINCT ON clause. In other words, output rows are filtered so that only one row is shows for each distinct set of values in the GROUP BY clause. If two or more output rows would have otherwise had the same set of values for the GROUP BY columns, then one of the rows is chosen arbitrarily.

Your query 1 would cause an error in most databases, yes, but as long as you're only going to use it with sqlite, it's perfectly fine.

---

An alternative to finding the highest version of each item uses the window functions added in Sqlite 3.25:

```
SELECT item_id, version_number, content
FROM (SELECT item_id, version_number, content
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY version_number DESC) AS rnk
      FROM item_version) AS sq
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY item_id;
```

giving

```
item_id     version_number  content   
----------  --------------  ----------
1           1                         
2           2               Content B 
3           2                         
4           2
```

This one should work on other databases like Oracle, as long as they support window functions too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so is there a better way to write query2 ?

Comment: Would `partition by` query be better in performance than query2 ?

Comment: @user1046037 I don't know off the top of my head. But for sqlite specific code, the first one will be more efficient than either.

Comment: @user1046037 One thing that would be a big boost for the window function one in sqlite at least is to change your primary key definition to `primary key (item_id, version_number desc)`.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, my impression was that partition by and order would be more expensive than query2, I could be completely wrong. Adding version_number desc index might be expensive at the time of insertion.

Comment: It's no different from grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn does a really good job of explaining the issue.  A typical way to solve this uses a correlated subquery:

```
select iv.*
from item_version iv
where iv.version_number = (select max(iv2.version_number)
                           from item_version iv2
                           where iv2.item_id = iv.item_id
                          );
```

With an index on `item_version(item_id, version_number)` this may be the fastest way to get the results that you want.  You already have this index with your primary key definition.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't having a primary key also serve as an index on `item_id` and `version_number` ?

Comment: @user1046037 . . . Very true.  I clarified in the answer.